# If an ode is expressed $y'=f(t,y)$, is it possible to get multiple values of $y$ if $t$ is held constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In the context of numerical methods, we often solve differential equations using step-wise methods like the Forward Euler equation where we solve for the dependent variable $y$ incrementally using the following equation $y_2=y_1+hf(y,t)$, where $y'=f(y(t),t)$. Since both $y$ and $y'$ are both dependent on $t$, is it possible to realize multiple values of $y$ (ie $y_1, y_2, y_3$, etc) if $t$ is held constant?

Comment: You mean like in implicit Euler? Yes, that is possible, but usually you get one solution close-by and all the others far away from the last point.

Comment: Actually I was referring to forward explicit Euler. Honestly I might be a bit confused on the difference between the two. Maybe that's lending to my overall confusion

Comment: One example is $y' = 2 \sqrt y $   where $y=0$  is one answer, but $y=x^2$ for $x \geq 0$ is a different solution.

Comment: I thought y=x^2 for x>0 was the only general solution, when you use separation of variables?

Comment: Before you separate, you have to exclude all cases where division-by-zero could occur. Here this case actually gives a solution. This equation is special in that the solutions for $y>0$ reach the solution $y=0$ in finite time (going backwards). In the more usual case with a Lipschitz condition, distance between solutions only decreases exponentially, never reaching zero.